# How call jquery function inside php code - $ is not defined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, alert

I want to use [jQuery-confirm dialog](https://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/) instead of echoing a Javascript `alert` from PHP. When I run following code it shows me this error:

> $ is not defined

```
echo "<script>$.alert({title: 'Alert!',content: 'Simple alert!',});</script>";
```

Comment: That error means you have not included jquery.js in your page, or if you have its either in the wrong place, or the path to the file is wrong.

Comment: Is because you are using a jquery or a plugin, try tu use native javascript alert alert('message');

Comment: @JorgeMejia OP wants to use jQuery

Comment: Try running a simple JavaScript alert first. If that works, then make sure you are include jQuery in your file.

Comment: It is same when I add jquery.min.js to my page :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be sure to include the jQuery library first.

Then, if it still do not work, like you say in comments, try wrapping your alert inside a `$(document).ready()`:

```
echo "<script>$(document).ready(function(){$.alert({title: 'Alert!',content: 'Simple alert!'});});</script>";
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried but it makes no difference :/ "$ is not defined"

Comment: Then the most possible issue is with your jQuery library inclusion. Open the console and look for an error about this. It probably is a "404 not found" due to a bad path to your jquery.min.js.

Comment: If you can't find anything, can you give me a live link to your page? I will check it.

Answer (score 0):

You must understand that Javascript runs on the client side (the browser) try outputting this to a html page while including the script source for Jquery-confirm and you'll see that $.alert started working.

Comment: I got you @Zatara7 , I already know it . I need it when I detect that "this username is already exist" . I can do it only in php (server side) but when i detect it I must show alert dialog and I downt want to use simple javascript alert :/

Comment: Why don't you make a separate controller in php that your javascript from the client side sends data to it using ajax, then use the information that it returns to make the jquery confirm code appear.

Answer (score 0):

you want confirm that [jQuery](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery/) library is linked or not... or You can place your code after the jQuery library included...

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it didn't solve the problem  :/

Answer (score 0):

Endless thanks to all. I have solved my problem with moving script libraries to my header section. And it works now ;)